# Ignore specific rows and merge operation using on conflict in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

Table Structure:

```
create table example_test (a_id integer, b_id integer, c_id integer, flag integer);
```

Unique Constraint:

```
Alter table example_test
add constraint u_key unique(a_id, b_id, c_id);
```

My code:

```
with a_ins_upd as (
    Insert into example (a_id, b_id, c_id, flag)
        select x.a_id, x.b_id, x.c_id, x.flag
        from <input_tableType> x
    on conflict on constraint u_key
    do update
    set
        a_id = excluded.a_id,
        b_id = excluded.b_id,
        c_id = excluded.c_id,
        flag = excluded.flag
    where flag = 0
)
```

Operations on Data:

[image: Operations on Data]

[image: Result should be]

I want to ignore the records with flag=1, and do the Upsert on the other records.

Comment: `<input_tableType> x` -> `(select * from yourtable where flag<>1) x`. Your query isn't complete (it's only showing a CTE clause) so I can't say for sure, but I think once you've made that change you'll also drop `where flag=0` from the ON CONFLICT clause.

Comment: This way, I cant update the existing records with flag=0 to flag=1. Once I update, I want to ignore. Lets say, it become soft deleted. yes cte I am showing, this is just a part of the code.

Comment: So, at one point of time, only one record with flag = 0 will be present , but multiple records with flag = 1 may be present, because they are soft deleted. And upsert should be based on other 3 columns. I was trying with partial index, but could not achive what I want. Any idea would be appreciable.

Comment: Usually soft delete implementing via `instead of delete` triggers...

Answer (score 0):

Basically I think you want a filtered unique key.

Instead of:

```
alter table example_test
add constraint u_key unique(a_id, b_id, c_id);
```

You could do:

```
create unique index example_idx on example_test(a_id, b_id, c_id) where flag = 0;
```

You can then use a regular `insert ... on conflict` clause (without the `where` clause in `on conflict`).

Comment: Yes exactly I tried to do by using a partial Index. But, this is the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65142186/partial-unique-index-not-working-with-on-conflict-clause-postgresql

Comment: Not working with partial Index, also. Its Inserting, instead of Updating.

Answer (score 0):

ok, Exclusion Constraint is not supported by on conflict clause. Makes sense, it can update multiple records. Only way is to handle programmatically.